# Bootstrap Vue effects not visible in electron vue app (Desktop UI)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, electron-vue

I am using [Electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) to create desktop application. I was trying to use [boostrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) in my app. When I open the app I can see all the functionality of boostrap(button tables) but none of the styling associated with it (color, font etc..)

Am I doing something wrong or is bootstrap vue not compatible with electron style apps ?

Comment: Do you have a link to a repo? What errors are you getting? How are you loading CSS? Are you using `vue-cli`?

Comment: I am using electron-vue steps which I am hoping in on top of vue-cli. I do not get any errors I just dont see any styling.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was reading some blogs and apparently boostrap-vue does not work with desktop apps. I had more luck with using [element UI](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US)

Comment: BootstrapVue does indeed support running under Electron.  Just make sure you are using the latest electron-vue, bootstrap-vue and vue releases.

Answer (score 1):

The right installation procedure is described into the documentation: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs

Into your project root folder, install prerequesites:

```
# With npm
npm install vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap

# With yarn
yarn add vue bootstrap-vue bootstrap
```

After that, you have to open the main.js file ant had this portion of code just before the "new Vue(...)" call:

```
// Activate bootstrap vue
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

A blog post describe it perfectly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-using-bootstrap4

Answer (score 0):

BootstrapVue does support beig run under Electron.

See https://github.com/loopmode/electron-webpack-quick-start/tree/bootstrap-vue-ts and https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/issues/302#issuecomment-508911966